# Stopping automatic award for answer which doesn't answer the question

Tags: support, bounty, not-an-answer

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076660/how-do-i-add-a-strip-and-tile-to-windows-media-center-start-menu) which provided steps on how to get an icon displayed in Windows Media Center. However when it was selected, it didn't actually launch `notepad.exe` - so I asked a question "How can I get an executable to launch when it is selected?"

After no-one had answered, I offered up two bounties on it and it's been upvoted 12 times.

One person has responded with an "answer", which isn't at all.

- The first part of the answer states that I need to use the `RegisterMceApp.exe` - however the question very clearly states that I do this along with the command line arguments (in fact, if I didn't do that then I would never have been able to show the screenshot that I did with the error message).
- The second (and largest) part of the answer talks about differentiating between an app launched from Windows Media Center vs one launched from the desktop and how to handle returning to Windows Media Center after it has been exited - except that the question was never about it (in fact, I cannot get the app to launch at all, so it's completely irrelevant).

I've downvoted the answer and clearly pointed out why it doesn't actually answer anything but four other people have voted it up, suggesting that they haven't really read the question or answer.

I'm fully aware of the rules around automatic rewarding of a bounty but, right now, the system is going to award 50 points to a +3 voted answer (on a +12 voted question) which makes absolutely no attempt to actually answer the question.

Short of changing my question to point out in big capital letters that the one answer isn't an answer and hoping people see it and downvote accordingly (which, lets be honest, isn't going to happen), is there anything else I can do? Maybe a diamond moderator?

Comment: You don't *state* that an answer doesn't answer your question, rather, you recognize that your question, as is, wasn't clear, and people ended up misunderstanding what you were asking.  Learn from that, and make your questions clearer in the future, so that people will be less likely to misunderstand your question.

Comment: @Servy The problem is that the answer given answers a question that I don't remotely ask. I'm not sure how you can deal with that scenario!

Comment: As I said, you can make your question clearer so that people are less likely to misinterpret it.  If it's hard to understand what your question is asking, it's more likely someone will misinterpret it and answer a different question than what you asked, and it will increase the odds that those voting on the post will realize that it's incorrect and vote accordingly.

Comment: A more glaring problem is the answer is entirely copied from from elsewhere. I don't expect it'll last through the grace period.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure how I can make it any clearer. I provide the code, the commands to enable it, the screen shot, the link to the documentation, I quote the line in the documentation and I even mention in the bounty that I'm looking for an answer based on the steps taken above - and yet get an answer which doesn't relate to any of that. How much more precise can I possibly be?

Comment: @Richard That is of course the million dollar question, my point is that's all you can really focus on.  The biggest thing is that you start out by saying you want to be able to launch an exe from WMC, but only by the end are you describing that you're doing it and it's not working.  If you *open* with something more along the lines of "When I'm launching an executable from WMC I'm getting an error stating [...]." and *then* backtrack and explain the context later, it helps.  Getting to the actual question *immediately*, rather than only at the very end, is typically best.

Comment: @Servy Thank you, that's good feedback and one I'll remember :)

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299148/prevent-auto-awarding-bounty-in-case-up-voted-answer-is-not-correct

Comment: @Servy I've made some edits. If you get a chance, can you let me know what you think?

Comment: @Richard It looks much better.